# Jquery: How to get the value of button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to create a css generator using jquery and i got aproblem when i try to get the value of the button pressed.
I try the same function with a select and it workes fine.
I just want when i click on the red button the background color change to red and the same for all the button.
There is my snippet code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script>
  var css_background = 'brown';
  
  function css_func (){
   css_tag = ".result{background:" + css_background + " ; width:500px; height:400px; border:"+css_background+" solid 2px;}";
   $('style').replaceWith('<style>'+css_tag+'</style>');
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){
   css_func();
   
      //change the color with selector (It's work fine)
   $('select').change(function(){
    css_background = $(this).val();
    css_func();
   });
      
      //change the color with button
   $('button').change(function(){
    css_background = $(this).val();
    css_func();
   });
  });
   </script>

   <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="left">
    <button style="background-color:red;width:50px;height:30px" class="Red" value='red'></button>
    <button style="background-color:black;width:50px;height:30px" class="Black" value='black'></button>
    <button style="background-color:blue;width:50px;height:30px" class="Blue" value='blue'></button>
    <button style="background-color:pyrple;width:50px;height:30px" class="Purple" value='purple'></button>
    <button style="background-color:brown;width:50px;height:30px" class="Brown" value='brown'></button>
        
    <select class="elem" style="width:50px;height:30px">
     <option value='red'>Red</option>
     <option value='black'>Black</option>
     <option value='blue'>Blue</option>
     <option value='purple'>Purple</option>
     <option value='brown'>Brown</option>
    </select>
   </div>
     
   <div class="right">
    <div class="result"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
   </body>
```

Comment: Buttons aren't "changed", they're "clicked". (use `$('button').click` instead). Also, they don't really have "values" AFAIK  (they're not inputs). You can put the value in `data-color` or something instead and access it with `$(this).data('color')`.

Comment: @mpen, `button` can have a `value` attribute. That's why it's so much more powerful than `input[type=button]`.

Comment: @WiktorBednarz ```input[type="button"]``` can have value attributes. That's actually the only way you can create the visible text label for input buttons. A ```<button>``` is more powerful because it is not a self closing element, and can have child elements, which ```input[type="button"]``` can not.

Comment: @scottohara, I did not say that `input[type=button]` cannot have `value`. ;-) By saying that `button` is more powerful I meant that it can have different caption (visible text) and send different value to the server, whereas `input[type=button]` sends to the server the same text that is showed to the user.

Comment: my apologies @WiktorBednarz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$('button').change()` to `$('button').click`. Clicking a button doesn't necessarily change its state, which is what *change* is looking for.